# video tag is not displaying error message in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I am using html5 video. if the format is not supported then it should display the message. But it is supported another message. I have defined the video element as

```
    <video controls>
        <source src="some source locaaly" type="video/webm" />
        <source src="some source locaaly" type="video/mp4" />
        Video not suppoerd
    </video>
```

It is showing error message invalid source. But it is working in safari.

Comment: Try changing from relative to absolute path, or vice versa

Comment: actually i am dynamically setting the source. like `$("#video").attr('src', @Url.Content("~/Home/Date"))`. I am returning the file from there. `video` is the id for the video tag

Comment: Which IE version(s)???